# Format the Previous and the Next links for mobile devices in Twenty Sixteen theme

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I try for several days to change how are displayed the **Previous** and the **Next** navigation links for single posts on mobile devices in a Wordpress Twenty Sixteen child theme, more specifically, their font properties, but  without success. I am able to format them for desktops, but not for mobile devices. I know about CSS media queries, but I am unable to find a solution in my situation. Can someone who knows this theme to suggest me any ideas?

This is what I tried the last time:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 75em) {
   .post-navigation a .post-title {
      color: #007acc;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.25;
   }
}
```

This is my development site: dev.infopsi.md

This is a single post: http://dev.infopsi.md/2016/10/17/salut-lume.html

Comment: A live-working-example is what we need in order to help. Without looking at the actual working page it's really hard to understand why something doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see any prev/next links there...

Comment: So you should give a link to the exact place :) don't expect someone to figure it...

Comment: I don't see any `@media screen and (max-width: 75em` in your code... I only see `min-width`

Comment: Are you sure? this gives me error 404...

Comment: copy & paste the exact link in your comment...

Comment: @Dekel Ok, I shared it through Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_IL1PLucRCATWllemw4ZERIclE

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for... the code is not **inside** the CSS file that your website is loading..

Comment: I don't need firefox browser... note that this link **is not** the one you provided in the prev comment

Comment: Your website is using `http://dev.infopsi.md/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css?ver=4.6.1` (and not the link you have). Make sure you website loads the correct files.

Comment: @Derek No, that is the parent theme. The child theme also works, I see my changes, but I cannot change only what I asked.

Comment: it's Dekel (not derek). And note that you put the `@media screen and (max-width: 75em)` **inside** the `@media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em)` block (which is invalid).

Comment: @Dekel Sorry for "derek"! And thank you very much for your help! I opened the `@media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em)` and I forgot to close it, so the second `@media screen` became nonfunctional, the result being two lost days :(. Thank you again! Cheers!

Comment: Care if I add this as the answer so you can accept/vote it?

Comment: @Dekel OK, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the CSS file, which wasn't valid.

The `@media screen and (max-width: 75em)` block was inside another `@media` block (which is **not** valid CSS):

You **can't** do this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em) {
....
....
@media screen and (max-width: 75em) {
....
....
}
```

You must first close the first `@media` block:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em) {
....
....
}
@media screen and (max-width: 75em) {
....
....
}
```

The easiest way to find such errors is to use a CSS validator:
https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/